# Submit form without form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

This might look as the dumb question, but I hope it's not.
I have a PHP file delete.php that will delete selected users (it is not ready yet, but I will write it after I finish my HTML model).
So, on my HTML model I have the following:

```
<li><button class="sexybutton">
  <span><span><span class="add">Add</span></span></span>
</button></li>
```

This `sexybutton` is the button styling I've downloaded. So, how to make it post the selected user list to a PHP file without putting a `<form>` tag inside (it will brake all the structure otherwise and will not be valid)?

I could use jQuery (or JS), but I still do not know how to do this. If PHP would have something like "onclick" function :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but do you want to delete or add user?

Comment: Put a form anyway and use jQuery. You can then use `$('form').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });` to make sure it doesn't fire the submit.

Comment: A form element shouldn't break the structure and should be valid. Your span should be a submit button.

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery documentation particularly how to make an ajax call.  Then you could just call the function with a parameter based on userid e.g. `...<li><button class="sexybutton" onclick="addUser(someID)">...` and make a javascript function to handle the addUser call.

Comment: use jquery's post method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: PHP is a server side language. An onclick event would be useless since there is no one to trigger it.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a server side language. Just some kind of dreams about it :)
---
Sanja, I want do delete user. I just unintentionally pasted the button styling called "Add". These are almost the same in the code, sorry for that inconvenience

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send an ajax request without a form, like this :

```
$('.sexybutton').on('click', function() {
    var users = $.map( $('li.users'), function(el) {
       return $(el).text();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url : 'delete.php',
        data: users
    });
});
```

just create the data you need, and send it ?

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="your_form">
<ul>
<li><button class="sexybutton" onclick="$('#your_form').submit();">
  <span><span><span class="add">Add</span></span></span>
</button></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

explanation:

wrap your existing code with form element, give some unique id to your form (e.g. your_form) and then add attribute onclick to your button and fill it with some jquery syntax (or pure javascript if you wish):

```
$('#your_form').submit();
```

this will do the submit job.

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?

Comment: Op specifically asked for a way to send data without using a `<form>` tag

Comment: @andrew because he thinks it will produce not valid code and break structure, which is not true.

Comment: But it still produces not valid code within the `<li>` tag. By W3C and PHPStorm